# Show packages and java classes in tree structure in Elicpse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I want to show all projects in workspace in tree-structure.

I have created plugin from 'Hello World' template. First node of Tree should contain 'project name', children of this node will be list of packages and children of packages will be java classes of that packages. I want do some operation when user clicks on leaf node(i.e. java class).

I got list of projects from workspace by this

```
IProject[] projects = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getProjects();
```

Now I really dont know how to access packages and java classes from here and show them in tree.

Comment: Very broad question. You will need to learn about the [Eclipse JDT Abstract Syntax Tree](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJDT/article.html)

Comment: Thanks @greg-449  Now I got how to get package and java information from project. Still I am not able to figure out how to render this info in tree structure. Just give me a direction.

Comment: Use the [JFace TreeViewer](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-TreeViewer/TreeViewerArticle.htm)

Comment: Why is what you're doing different from the Package Explorer view?

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Almost nothing. Just my requirement is slightly different than how 'Package Explorer view' works that when we double click on java class in package explorer view, it gets open in java editor. Instead of that I just want to show number of fields and methods that class have in my UI.

Comment: @BhushanPatil Just use the `SelectionService`. When someones selects a class in the package explorer you'll get notified through the workbench selection service. So you can create a new view that listens for selected classes and shows then the desired information.

Comment: @TomSeidel So you mean, first I need to implement 'Package Explore view' in view of my plug-in and then listen to notification of `SelectionService` ?

Comment: @BhushanPatil no need for your own Package Explorer. You need something like your own Properties View that listen for selections via SelectionService from the JDT Package-Explorer or any other part providing selected Java-Classes.

Comment: Great @TomSeidel. 
If possible, share some link or article which does something like u described.

Comment: You can find under https://eclipse.org/articles/Article-WorkbenchSelections/article.html an old but good example about the solution....